# Torsion for a 3D curve can be positive or negative, while curvature is always taken to be positive. Why?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, curves, tangent-line

$$\frac{dB}{dS} = -\tau N = \tau(-N)$$
$$\frac{dT}{dS} = \kappa N$$

where $\tau$ is the torsion and $\kappa$ is the curvature.

$\frac{dT}{dS}$, by convention, is defined to be in the direction of $N$, and hence $\kappa$ is always positive. This also means that $\kappa$ is the magnitude of $\frac{dT}{dS}$.

But $\frac{dB}{dS}$ is defined to be in the direction of $N$ or $-N$; hence, $\tau$ can be positive or negative. If $\frac{dB}{dS}$ is taken to be in the direction of $N$, then $\tau = -\Big|\frac{dB}{dS}\Big|$ (always negative). If $\frac{dB}{dS}$ is taken to be in the direction of $-N$, then $\tau = \Big|\frac{dB}{dS}\Big|$ (always positive).

Is there any mistake in my conceptual understanding? Also, why do we have two separation signing conventions for curvature and torsion?

Comment: For a C^∞ parametrized curve in the plane, it makes sense to designate curvature as positive if the curve is bending counterclockwise and positive if clockwise. In 3-space, there is no clockwise or counterclockwise, so there is no basis for assigning a sign to the curvature of a smooth curve. (Worst case: Suppose your C^∞ curve is perfectly straight for a stretch. Here, the unit normal vector does not even exist.)

Comment: Once you choose your sign convention, say with $dB/ds =-\tau N$, the sign of $\tau$ can vary on the curve. The sign tells you whether the curve is twisting right- or left-handedly. Consider the circular helix $(\cos t, \sin t, bt)$, whose torsion has the sign of $b$.